# WCF RIA SubmitChanges doesn't send master properties back to the server side

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, ria

Look, I have these pretty simple model Master-Detail:

Hand is master of Fingers (finger is a detail of hand)

So on the client side:

```
Hand hand = domainService.Hands[0];                 //  get some hand, doesn't matter
...
Finger f = new Finger() { f.Id = Guid.NewId() };
f.Hand = hand;                                      //  make connection !!
domainService.Fingers.Add(f);
domainService.SubmitChanges(OnSubmitCompleted, null);   //  error is here
```

On the Server Side:

```
public void Insert<T>(T obj)
{
    try
    {
        using (ISession session = _factory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);   //  NHibernate error: not-null property references a null or transient value
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ;
    }
}
```

***The problem actually is about not sending associations back via WCF wire. So On the server side the Hand property is NULL, but it shouldn't (violation) - I just want to refresh my finger.Hand property***

It's not even a composition - I don't need this cause of its limitations

here is the metaAttribute class:

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(Finger.FingerMetadata))]
public partial class Finger
{
    //[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    //[Exclude]
    public virtual Guid HandID { get; set; }
    //{
    //    get { return Hand.Id; }
    //}

    internal sealed class FingerMetadata
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id  { get; set; }

        [Include]
        //[RoundtripOriginal]
        //[ExternalReference]
        [Association("Finger-Hand", "HandID", "Id")]
        //[ConcurrencyCheck]
        //[Composition]
        public Hand Hand { get; set; }
    }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(Hand.HandMetadata))]
public partial class Hand
{
    internal sealed class HandMetadata
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id  { get; set; }

        [Include]
        //[ExternalReference]
        [Association("Hand-Finger", "Id", "HandID")]
        //[Composition]
        public IList<Finger> Fingers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I saw the same problem here http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/205220/480824.aspx, but nobody knows..
Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: I found here the differences between WCF Ria and WCF DataServices:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/154141/397408.aspx#397408

That's what I looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for help with this using RIA services (as opposed to Data services)

I've worked quite a bit with these 2 technologies in the recent past and I provided some information on the SL forums link you posted above:

["One to many association is null on Server side"](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/205220/576124.aspx#576124) (forums.silverlight.net)

Comment: I see, actually it's only solution;

The main thing that our POCO objects have to have foreign-keys ID to another master entities, that's really bad story, and RIA force you to do this.

Another problem - if you change master on the client side and send this graph to the server - You'll get just master Id, no more, that's a pity

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. Apply [composition] to your association
2. Make update methods for all lower enties 
   Overload protected override bool PersistChangeSet() on the domain service:

   ```
   protected override bool PersistChangeSet() 
   { 
       Customer changedCustomer; 
       bool success = true;
       foreach (var item in ChangeSet.ChangeSetEntries) 
       { 
          if (item.Entity.GetType() == typeof(Customer)) 
          { 
             changedCustomer = (Customer)item.Entity; 
             success = changedCustomer.Save(); 
             if (!success) 
               break; 
          } 
      } 
      return success;
   ```

   }

See http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/07.aspx